# Highchart in ASP MVC page load not working properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a question for Highchart using in ASP MVC5. I have 6 charts and I am showing just the one for the first page load. All my tags for chart creation and data in partialview. my javascript is also in partialview and I removed the javascript function from the partial view but the problem is still on.
The problem is I am refreshing the data in partial view and show it every minute
by

```js
$(function () {
        setInterval(function () { $('#container').load('/Dashboard/GetShow'); }, 60000);
    });
```

but after the next minute refresh page shows all charts not only the one.

my functions are:

```js
$('.show-chart').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.chart-title').html($(this).attr('title'));
        $('.chart-section').hide();
        $('.show-chart').removeClass('active');
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $(window).load(function (event) {
        $('.chart-section').hide();
        $('.chart-title').html($('.show-chart.active').attr('title'));
        $($('.show-chart.active').attr('href')).show();
    });
```

Could you help on this issue? Regards

Comment: Where are you placing `$(window).load(function (event) {...`? Is it in partialView?

Comment: First partialview. Then I remove it from the partialview and put it in the main view. But problem is still on.

Comment: Hide functionality is in `$(window).load(function (event) {...` and timer load `/Dashboard/GetShow` partialview. So, hiding functionality should placed in refreshed partialview. I mean, you should call hiding after refresh partialview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like following:

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(function () { $('#container').load('/Dashboard/GetShow', function() {
        $('.chart-section').hide();
        $('.chart-title').html($('.show-chart.active').attr('title'));
        $($('.show-chart.active').attr('href')).show();
    }); }, 60000);
});
```

---

**EDIT: Better Approach**

```
function hideCharts() 
{
    $('.chart-section').hide();
    $('.chart-title').html($('.show-chart.active').attr('title'));
    $($('.show-chart.active').attr('href')).show();
}

$(function () {

    // When page first load
    hideCharts();

    // Every time interval
    setInterval(function () { $('#container').load('/Dashboard/GetShow', function() {
        hideCharts();
    }); }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: Ok. I tried this, Before your suggestion I show one chart from 6 charts. I tagged it as active in html. after one minute page show all six charts. and 
 after your suggestion the view is working like this; it shows all six charts in first page load and then show exect one chart after one minute. I think it's working but now I have another issue, what will I do from the first load?

Comment: Ok. as your suggestion I corrected the functions. It is working great now. thanks.